# VBA open variable Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a consolidate workbook which open other excel files, copy and paste some tables.

The problem is that the number of these excel files will change as well their names.

For example I might have these files in one week:
file A
file B
file C

and these other files the week after:
file B
file C
file D
file E

The consolidate excel workbook must be able to open all these files without making modification to the VBA code every time.

Do you have any idea? Please write few code lines if you have a good idea

Thank you

Comment: do the files follow any particular pattern in names? are they all in any particular folder?

Comment: The way this site works is that *you* have to write some code, and we can help with that code.  We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: are the files always in the same directory?  and removed when done?  if so you can iterate though each file in the directory one at a time and do the desired processing.

Comment: Raugmor and xQbert: yesthe directory will always be the same. 
No they are not removed when done. The names will not follow a pattern in general. Actually, iterating each file in a directory might work. Is it easy to code?

Comment: Put all the files in a folder and use `Dir()` to loop over the files.  Tons of examples here on SO alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Thank you for the suggestion. I created a loop on the directory and I am posting the solution for future reference

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

myPath = "C:\Desktop\Common Folder Test\"

myExtension = "*.xls"

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set wb2 = Workbooks("Consolidated data.xlsm")
Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)

r2 = 1
Do While myFile <> ""

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
i = 2

Do While i <= 4
    r = 3
    Do While wb.Worksheets(i).Cells(r, 3) <> ""
    r = r + 1
    Loop
    r = r - 1

    c = 1
    Do While wb.Worksheets(i).Cells(2, c) <> ""
    c = c + 1
    Loop
    c = c - 1

    wb.Worksheets(i).Range(wb.Worksheets(i).Cells(2, 1), wb.Worksheets(i).Cells(r, c)).Copy
    ws1.Cells(r2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    i = i + 1
    r2 = r2 + r - 1

Loop

wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
myFile = Dir
Loop

MsgBox "Task Complete!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```